# How to create associative array with Id and Value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table that contains **id** and **weight**.
I want to put both in an associative array.

Right now I've managed to put only the **weight** in an array:

```
$weight= array();
$stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_weight");
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 $weight[] = $row['weight'];
}
```

I want to also put the **id** and make it an associative array.

For example for **id** = 1 and **weight** = 50, I want to be able to do something like:

```
$weight = array("1"=>"50");
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set your key when you append the value. As long as `id` is unique you shouldn't have any problems

```
$weight= array();
$stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_weight");
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $weight[$row['id']] = $row['weight'];
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. I have another question if you don't mind. Supposed this is the output of the query http://i.imgur.com/EsSSWFv.png, how can I pair up those id's with the same value? For example in the picture 1 and 3, 2 and 4, 5 and 6? And also 7 and 9, id must not be used twice..

Comment: Also, just `SELECT id, weight` not `*` unless you later need the other columns.

Comment: @FewFlyBy if you have a new question, please post a new question - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do

```
$weight[$row['id']] = $row['weight'];
```